# Make sure the orientation of phone is landscape always to view the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I am building a website and it works fine on the mobile also but only when it is in the landscape orientation. Meaning in a portrait view some of the elements become distorted.

Is there a way to make sure that the website is always oriented in landscape mode no matter what?

I tried this from a related answer:

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
  body {  
    height: 100vw;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
  body {  
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this won't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need of the second rule `orientation:landscape`

Answer (score 0):

A correction stated in the comments did the job. Following is the answer:

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
  body {  
    height: 100vw;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```